# How to find empty branches and tags in git

Tags: git, git-svn

I've migrated a big svn repository with hundreds of branches and tags, split them into multiple repositories and now i'm looking to check if there are any empty* branches/tags in these repositories that should be deleted before pushing the migration live.

Is there a faster way to find this than having to go to every repository and checkout every branch ?

---

*For the purpose of this question, "empty branch" or "empty tag" means a branch or tag that points to a commit that contains no files.

Comment: Did you used https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git ?

Comment: no - used git svn fetch plus my own adaption of git_fast_filter, see more at https://github.com/maxandersen/jbosstools-gitmigration

Comment: Interesting. By "empty tag" or "empty branch", do you mean empty directories (you shouldn't see any since Git doens't version empty dirs)? Or a commit with 0 files in it?

Comment: Based on the accepted answer and the OP's own, the question was asking about branches whose tip commit has no files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `git ls-tree <branch/tag> | wc -l` for every branch and tag using the programming language of you choice and check for `0`.  You get a list of branches with `git branch` and a list of tags with `git tag`.

Here is a simple example for branches using bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

for branch in $(git branch | cut -c 3-)
do
  if [ $(git ls-tree $branch | wc -m) -eq 0 ]
  then
    echo "branch $branch is empty"
  fi
done
```

Comment: This doesn't work.  Proof: `git checkout -b new_branch`, `git checkout some_branch`, `git commit`, `git ls-tree new_branch`.  The final `ls-tree` command lists the files that were committed on *some_branch*.  Therefore, the above doesn't detect "empty branches".

Comment: `git checkout -b new_branch` does not create an empty branch.  It creates a new branch that points to your current `HEAD`.  Try the following instead to create an empty branch: `git checkout -b new_branch && git rm --cached -r . && git commit --message "empty"`.

Answer (score 0):

I actually end up doing this script for it:

https://github.com/maxandersen/jbosstools-gitmigration/blob/master/deleteemptybranches.sh

```
    ## this will treat $1 as a repository and go through it and delete all branches and tags with empty content.

export GIT_DIR=$1/.git
export GIT_WORK_TREE=$1

echo Looking for empty branches in $1
git branch | while read BRANCH
do
 REALBRANCH=`echo "$BRANCH" | sed -e 's/\*//g'`
 NOFILES=`git ls-tree $REALBRANCH | wc -l | tr -d ' '`
# echo $NAME "$REALBRANCH" $NOFILES
 if [[ "$NOFILES" == "0" ]]
  then
     git branch -D $REALBRANCH 
  fi
done

git tag | while read BRANCH
do
 REALBRANCH=`echo "$BRANCH" | sed -e 's/\*//g'`
 NOFILES=`git ls-tree $REALBRANCH | wc -l | tr -d ' '`
# echo $NAME "$REALBRANCH" $NOFILES
 if [[ "$NOFILES" == "0" ]]
  then
     git tag -d $REALBRANCH 
  fi
done
```