# Git Command to List Merged Branches

Tags: git, branch, git-branch

Is there a way to list the branches that have been **merged** into the current working tree?  The following is close:

```
git branch -r --merged
```

However, this also includes empty branches.  For example, at some point before the latest commit on the current branch, I ran the following:

```
git checkout -b empty_branch
git push -u origin empty_branch
```

Now, the first command includes *empty_branch* in the resulting list.  I found a related question asking [how to find empty branches in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12686027/how-to-find-empty-branches-and-tags-in-git), but the accepted answer doesn't work for branches without commits.  Is there any way to detect commit-less branches in git, or to otherwise filter such branches out from the results of `git branch --merged`?

Comment: There's no such thing as an "empty branch", in Git. The new branch you created has all the same commits as the current branch. For the question to which you linked, the goal was to find branches whose tip commit contained no files (an empty *tree*).

Comment: @torek Do you have a proposed re-wording then, to more clearly identify branches that meet the above criteria?  I still need an answer to the question of how to get a list of these branches, even if "empty branch" isn't the correct git terminology.

Comment: Doing a `git log` might be helpful for you:

`git log --color --graph --pretty=format:'\''%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset'\'' --abbrev-commit`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're working off at least one faulty assumption about Git.  This is not an *unreasonable* assumption, as Git is weird, but it throws your whole question off a bit.

In Git, branch *names* don't really mean as much as most people think they do, at least at first.  A branch name simply holds the hash ID of some existing commit.  There's an underlying entity that people *also* call "a branch", and it consists of some or all of the commits that are *reachable from* the tip commit as defined by the branch name.  For (much) more about this, see [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452) and [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/), but let's try for a quick summary:

- What Git is really all about is *commits*.  Each commit is identified by its own unique hash ID.  No other commit can ever have this hash ID.  The contents of a commit include a snapshot—made from the index, rather than from the work-tree, but I will try not to get into all those hairy details here—and include the name and email address of the author of the commit, the same for the committer (usually the same person), and two date-and-time-stamps: one for author, one for committer.  They also include the log message the committer supplied at the time he/she/they/pronoun-of-choice made the commit.  Perhaps most importantly, the contents of a commit include the raw hash IDs of any commits that should be considered immediate predecessors of that commit.
- In other words, each commit has some set of *parent* hash IDs, most commonly just one hash ID.  These parent IDs make commits form backwards-looking chains: from a *last* commit, we can go back to a previous commit.  From there, we can go back one more step, and so on.  So if a branch name like `master` holds the hash ID of the *last* commit we should consider to be part of the branch, the remaining commits are that commit's parent(s), the parent(s) of the parent(s), and so on.  If the hash ID of the `master` tip commit is `H` and its parent is `G` and `G`'s parent is `F` and so on, we have:

  ```
  ... <-F <-G <-H   <-- master
  ```

  and that's what a branch is: it's either the name, or the series of commits ending at `H`, or both: we tend to have to guess what someone means when they say "the `master` branch".

What `git branch --merged` does is:

- Find the hash ID of the current branch (`HEAD`).
- For all branch names *B* <s>skipping over the current branch (as read from `HEAD`)</s> oops: Git *doesn't* skip the current branch, which is sort of annoying:

  - Is the commit identified by *B* an ancestor of the commit identified by `HEAD`?<sup>1</sup>  If so, print the name *B*.  In any case, move on to the next name.

So if part of the graph looks like:

```
             I--J   <-- feature2
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- master (HEAD)
      \
       K--L   <-- feature1
```

the two commits that `git branch --merged` will test are `J` and `L`, as compared to the current commit `H`.  If `J` is an ancestor of `H`—but it's not—this would print `feature2`.  If `L` is an ancestor of `H`—but it's not—this would print `feature1`.  Of course, `H` is an ancestor of `H`, so this *does* print `master` (with a prefix `*` to indicate that it is the current branch).

If there's a *fourth* name that points to any of `F`, `G`, `H`, or any of the commits "behind" `F`, `git branch --merged` will print *that* name, too.

I *think* what you want is to print all names that point to any of the commits that are truly ancestors, and not any names that point directly to commit `H`.  The simplest way to do that is probably to let `git branch --merged` print everything, then remove from the list any name whose hash ID matches that of `HEAD`.

To remove such names, use `git rev-parse` on each name.  Use `git rev-parse HEAD` to find the hash ID of the current branch, i.e., the actual hash ID for `H` in the drawing above.  Then, using `git rev-parse` again on each name from `git branch --merged`, if the result is the same as the first `git rev-parse`, discard that name.  Otherwise, keep that name.

(You will have to write a little bit of code for this.  If `git for-each-ref` could do `--not` and combine some boolean expressions, it could probably be done with that, but it doesn't do `--not` and combining.)

---

<sup>1</sup>The is-ancestor test that Git uses allows equality, i.e., it's ≤ rather than < (or more precisely, precedes-or-equals, ≼, vs ≺).  This is also true for `git merge --is-ancestor`.

Comment: This was close enough to mark it as the answer.  I actually want to exclude any branch that points to H, G, F...  Once L is merged into H, feature1 still points to L, so we know actual work was performed.  If feature1 points to H, G, F... then I can assume that no work has yet been performed on that branch that has been merged to master.  Does this make sense, or is it still confusing?  I came up with a way to get the list of branches that meet this criteria directly in a loop using rev-parse, but don't have my code handy at the moment.  I will post an answer here when I do have access.

Comment: Yes, that all seems to make sense.